# Sort associative array according to value without deleting keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

I have an array which i want to sort on the basis of its value. But when i'm using `rsort`, it deletes all the keys. I tried to flip array and then used `krsort`, but then it removes some key/values pairs which have the same key.

```
Array
(
    [533ae5a78ead0e8e118b4567] => 1
    [534d5a4b8ead0e5b73294d72] => 45
    [533ee8bc8ead0ec5138b4567] => 32
    [535f42748ead0ef72ec72731] => 1
    [537cc7128ead0e683071f3c0] => 2
    [5388795b8ead0ea32f208680] => 3
    [538c4f1a8ead0e75472f05b0] => 6
    [538963758ead0e6759208680] => 5
    [538961a58ead0e0459208680] => 3
    [5389616e8ead0ecc58208680] => 3
    [538962c68ead0eb6582098d8] => 2
    [538964c78ead0ec159208680] => 1
    [53887efc8ead0e2b35208680] => 1
    [538964678ead0ea659208680] => 3
)
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: why not use asort only

Comment: If you want to sort by __values__, not by __keys__, http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php The "a" functions maintain index associations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`arsort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php). From the manual:

> arsort — Sort an array in reverse order and maintain index association

Example:

```
$a = array(
    '533ae5a78ead0e8e118b4567' => 1,
    '534d5a4b8ead0e5b73294d72' => 45, 
    '533ee8bc8ead0ec5138b4567' => 32
);

arsort($a);
var_dump($a);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  '534d5a4b8ead0e5b73294d72' =>
  int(45)
  '533ee8bc8ead0ec5138b4567' =>
  int(32)
  '533ae5a78ead0e8e118b4567' =>
  int(1)
}
```

Comment: WTH. I think lot of coding in a single day is injurious to health. :D . Don't know how i forgot that. Thanks though.

Comment: Ok, save the file and shutdown the computer for a while! ;)