# Failing to sort a multi-dim associative array

Tags: php, arrays

Hope I dont confuse you but here goes.

I have a multiDim array where each key represents months. (`dataByMonth`)

So in the code bellow I loop through each month.

in the second `foreach` I check each element to be of type ( in this case `ward_`)

if the a `ward_` contains a `_perc` at the end of the string it is also left out.

This leaves me with a array like in the picture, where I have the wards with the amount of visits for that month.

This is where the proplem comes. I then try to sort that array `DESC by value` like this `arsort($resArr,SORT_NUMERIC);`  curtsy of [Sort associative array according to value without deleting keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205222/sort-associative-array-according-to-value-without-deleting-keys)    and  http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php

but that fails to sort the array.

I have tried

```
$resArr = array();
$returnArray = array();
$length = strlen($type);
foreach ($dataByMonth as $key =>$data) {
    foreach($data as $k => $v) {
        if (substr($k, 0, $length) == $type && substr($k, -5, 5) != "_perc") {
            $name = str_replace($type, "", $k);
            $elm_name = str_replace("_", " ", $name);
            $resArr[$elm_name] = $v;
        }
    }

    arsort($resArr,SORT_NUMERIC);

    $returnArray[$key] = $resArr;
}
```

Every month then gets added to a annual array which is then used on the report.

I have an array

[image]

Comment: You may want to share the input and expected output.

Comment: Don't you need to reset `$resArr` to an empty array before the second foreach?

Comment: @jh1711 Good point, but it still does not sort the concatenated array in the end.

Answer (score -2):

Using the [rsort](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) method works for me:

```
rsort($resArr);
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/ejAnF)

Comment: In the demo all keys has been removed.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte - as you stated in the comment under the original question, we do not know what the expected output should be. I assumed that the asker wanted the values sorted and I provided an answer that does just that. Do you have a magic ball that allows you to see what the asker wants, if so we should probably talk.

Comment: Thanks David, but as I did state above ` I then try to sort that array DESC by value `.

Comment: @morne - right, and that is the solution that I provided. Perhaps it would be more beneficial if you gave an example of how you wanted the array to be when it is all said an done.